Create range rings with varying radii based on column in standalone table around point feature described in same standalone table in ArcGIS Pro
I'm importing CSV data to have a visual representation of my data.
In the CSV I have 4 columns (Name, Latitude, Longitude, range).
I can easily plot the different points by displaying XY data, but can't find a way to display the range rings.
I tried the buffer tool and range rings tool, but either I must choose a fixed range or have a different table.
Which tool should be used for this?



By "range rings tool" do you mean the Generate Range Rings (Defense) tool or something else?

The buffer tool accepts a field as the buffer distance, have a read of the help file.

Thank you. Indeed I found it, although I can't select a a unit when using a field. Now the rings are based on meters instead of km, or any other unit I would like to use. Any suggestions?

If none of the existing tools does exactly what you want, and you're unwilling to provide the inputs they require, then you'll need to write your own tool. Fortunately, this is less than a hundred lines of documented code.

You can use the buffer tool:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/buffer.htm#GUID-42A39A8F-CFDB-4B34-88CB-4596EB832658
This allows the use of a field to determine distance.
You can put the unit in the cell.
But if you do not put the unit in, you need to be careful with the projection system. For example if you had 1, and your projection was WGS84 you would end up with a 1 degree buffer.
